# hours range and resetting the hours on the new day

Tags: php

I have the following code

```
$date = new DateTime($json->date);
$hour =  $date->format( 'H' );  
$range = range($hour, 23, 3); // get the range for the data to be provided;
        foreach($json->hourly as $hourlyData){

            if(in_array($hourlyData->hour, $range)){

                print_r($hourlyData->hour);echo '<br />'; 
            }
        }
```

the code above looks at current time. If time is 4, then it will add an echo for every 3 hours as the range would be (4,23, 3). This all is good. However, this above is only for current day. But for next day, I want the range to be reset and instead of from 4, it will be from 1 till 23. So the range will reset to (1,23,3) and so on.

Comment: just add another range starting from 1 and `foreach` it?

Comment: do you want me to put that as an answer? or you gonna delete the question because the solution is too obvious?

Comment: Take a look at DateInterval class to make sure it's working on differnt timezones / daylight saving times / leap years

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what you need to use is `DateInterval` not range ....

Try

```
$date = new DateTime("2012-4-12 4:20am");
$dv = new DateInterval('PT3H');
$totalInterval = 20 ; 
echo "<pre>" ;
echo $date->format('H') , PHP_EOL;
for($i = 0; $i < $totalInterval; $i++)
{
    $date->add($dv);
    echo $date->format('H') , PHP_EOL;

}
```

Output

```
04
07
10
13
16
19
22
01
04
07
10
13
16
19
22
01
04
07
10
13
16
```

I hope this helps